# Display Labels in Google Maps from Spreadsheet Mapper

Tags: google-maps, kml

How would I go about displaying labels on placemarks on the map canvas where the source kml comes from the Spreadsheet Mapper?

This particular use case is where we want to share and control the source spreadsheet in Google Docs, and have a display interface that is fairly ubiquitous, i.e. on thin blade client browsers, android browsers. Not either of these display devices will allow the use of Google Earth (thin blades don't have it installed cause of those well meaning network admins.... and droid GE is not able to display limited share files AFAIK).

It is highly desired to be able to edit the source data in a GDocs SS, since the placemark locations will rarely change, but the labels and comments should pretty straightforward edits.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/suggestions-for-simple-mapping-platform-for-alumni-web-site), and [this method](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm) of using a Google Spreadsheet on the backend to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a thought but perhaps publishing the google spreadsheet as XML then using XSLT to transform the XML in KML formatted document then you should be able to get a upto date version of your spreadsheet that everyone can edit in a common way (Google Docs) and then everyone can view it using google earth.

KML markup information found here https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

Good luck, I haven't had a need to make anything accessible spatially in this way but I think the concept is good.

Comment: Doh! disregard my post didn't even know spreadsheet mapper was an actual pre existing program, the concept was that good its already been done :)

Comment: Apologies for being cryptic.... Appreciate your thoughts