# How to integrate Google Drive with web mapping capabilities?

Tags: web-mapping, google-docs

I use a shared Google Drive spreadsheet to coordinate a large GIS mapping project.  The work involves processing thousands of [DOQQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_orthophoto_quadrangle) images.   Essentially, work is divided into study areas and then further into DOQQ boundaries that make up the study areas.

I am envisioning a dynamically updated web map that show which DOQQs have been processed within study areas.  In other words, as I update the shared spreadsheet, the web map should also update.  The attached image is a rough example of the type of data I wish to present.

Is this feat possible with any web mapping services (e.g. CartoDB)?  Which technologies should I pursue to accomplish this type of web mapping?

[image]

Comment: Sorta related is [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/suggestions-for-simple-mapping-platform-for-alumni-web-site), and [this](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried something like it, but certainly it should be possible.
[Realtime mapping](http://cartodb.com/realtime) is one of cartoDB selling points, although you would need to solve the issue of automating the update between Google drive and cartoDB's postGIS database.

If you have some experience in Web development, it should also be possible to write a JavaScript application that syncs with Google Drive directly. For example using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) with [Tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop). Again, I have never tried this, but it looks perfectly feasible. You can start from the Tabletop README and its [backbone example](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/blob/master/examples/backbone/backbone.html). Once you have set-up a backbone collection with your dynamic data, you can then use this data to draw a vector map in leaflet or OpenLayers. The application would then listen to a backbone "change:[attribute]" event that would fire a real-time update on the vector map.